# Check if path is empty in glob?

Tags: python, glob

Check if any folder in the glob search is empty and print their names.

There are some folders that are empty in the directories.

This is the code:

```
for i in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/testna/**' ,recursive = True):
    if not os.listdir(i): 
        print(f'{i} is empty' + '\n')
```

Returns:

```
NotADirectoryError
```

Comment: `iglob` returns also file paths, so before calling a method to see if a directory is empy you should call a method to see if the given path is actually a directory or not, using `isdir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding empty directories is a lot easier with `os.walk`:

```
import os
print([root for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/') if not files and not dirs])
```

Or if you prefer to print the files line by line:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
    if not files and not dirs:
        print(root)
```

Comment: Does this check the current working directory?Where to set the path as in the question?in order to start recursive search in that path?

Comment: `os.walk('/')` means to search recursively from the root directory. You can replace `'/'` with the path you want to start the search from.

Comment: why '/' means root directory?

Comment: This is simply how root directory is notated. You can read about root directory here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory It works if you are in Windows too, although if you are in Windows you can also use `r'C:\'` to refer to the root directory of the C drive.

Comment: And how to print each line below the other in the result? Tried the thing I had in my question but I don't know how to do it, can you edit your answer with the results being line by line. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with code to print the result line by line then.

Comment: The `print` function already outputs a trailing `\n'` by default. You can modify the code to suit your need for sure.

Comment: Something I noticed with your code is that it prints also folders that contain subfolders that contain data. Which shouldn't. I would need only the last folders in the tree that don't contain data themselves.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to exclude directories that contain subdirectories as well.